# Cannot find the type of subclass in DataType property

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008-sp1

In my xaml file for window in wpf project am using binding to the type in such way

```
<TreeView>
   <TreeView.Resources>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type spec:SectionContainer.SectionNode}">
...
```

where `SectionContainer.SectionNode` is subclass of partial class `SectionContainer` and `spec` is namespace of *current* assembly, defined in `Window` tag as:

```
xmlns:spec="clr-namespace:Proj.Sections".
```

There is no error while defining `spec`, but using SectionNode type in DataType property generates:

```
Cannot find the type 'spec:SectionContainer.SectionNode'. Note that type names are case sensitive.
```

I understand what this error means, but there is no reason for it to appear there. May be problem in using of partial class or in something else? All classes are defined as `public`.
My classes:

```
namespace Proj.Sections
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class SectionContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class SectionNode : SectionNode
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your class definitions (minus members) for your `SectionContainer` and `SectionNode` classes.

Comment: Ahh... I think that `Serialization` might be your problem. It doesn't work well with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. My WPF projects all have separate `SerializableXXX` classes for any objects that need serialization and the ones that are used in the UI have no serialization. As a test, try removing your `SerializableAttribute`s.

Comment: @Sheridan I removed using of x:Type and now have no problems, you may write ur comment as answer, may be it will help someone to resolve similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `SectionNode` subclass out of `SectionContainer` solves the problem. Before this I also tried to define `DataType` value in separate `<HierarchicalDataTemplate.DataType/>` tag, but it led to another error messages. So other ideas how to use subclasses and have no errors in the same time are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh... now that you have added your class definitions (please always show your relevant code *when* you ask your question), I think that I can see your problem. I had a similar situation where `Serialization` was the problem. For some unknown reason, it doesn't work well with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

To get around this problem, my WPF projects all have separate `SerializableXXX` classes for any objects that need serialization and the classes that are used in the UI and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface have no serialization. As a simple test, try removing your `SerializableAttribute`s and see if it makes any difference.